# Make ring in natural way

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a subset in a commutative ring $R$, such that:

- $1 \in S$
- $\forall x,y \in S \qquad xy\in S$

Define a relation $\sim$ on the Cartesian product $R\times S$ through $(r_{1},s_{1})\sim(r_{2},s_{2})$ if $\exists s\in S$ such that:

$$s(r_{1}s_{2}-r_{2}s_{1})=0$$

How can $R\times S/\sim$ be made into a ring in a natural way?

Can you help me with this question. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hint: how are rational numbers usually constructed from integers?

Comment: Oh okey..but how can it become a ring?

Comment: The same way we define ring of rational numbers. In this case, $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}-\left\{0\right\}$. Addition of $(p, q)$ and $(r, s)$ is defined as $(ps+qr, qs)$ etc. You need to prove these operations are well-defined and have desired properties, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same construction one have to do to obtain rational numbers from integers.

The operation you are looking for are those *defined* by the following equations:

$$[(r_1,s_1)]+[(r_2,s_2)] = [(r_1s_2+r_2s_1,s_1s_2)]$$
$$[(r_1,s_1)][(r_2,s_2)] = [(r_1r_2,s_1s_2)]$$

of course you have to prove that these are well defined, i.e. the definition doesn't depend on the choice of representants: 
if $(r'_1,s'_1) \sim (r_1,s_1)$ and $(r'_2,s'_2) \sim (r_2,s_2)$ the we want that 
$$(r_1s_2+r_2s_1,s_1s_2) \sim (r'_1s'_2+r'_2s'_1,s'_1s'_2)$$
and
$$(r_1r_2,s_1s_2) \sim (r'_1r'_2,s'_1s'_2)$$

If you choose to indicate by $\frac{r}{s}$ the equivalence class $[(r,s)]$ then these operation have the form
$$\frac{r_1}{s_1}+\frac{r_2}{s_2} = \frac{r_1s_2+r_2s_1}{s_1s_2}$$
and 
$$\frac{r_1}{s_1}\frac{r_2}{s_2} = \frac{r_1r_2}{s_1s_2}$$
respectively (are very likely as the operation you put on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/\sim$ to obtain $\mathbb Q$).

You can easily prove that $\mathbb Q$ is exactly obtained as this kind of ring by letting $R=\mathbb Z$ and $S=\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the so called localization of $R$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $S$.

$R \times S / \sim $ inherits a ring structure in the following way: $$\frac{r_{1}}{s_{1}} + \frac{r_{2}}{s_{2}} = \frac{r_{1}s_{2} + r_{2}s_{1}}{s_{1}s_{2}}$$ $$\frac{r_{1}}{s_{1}} \cdot \frac{r_{2}}{s_{2}} = \frac{r_{1}r_{2}}{s_{1}s_{2}}$$ where $\frac{r_{1}}{s_{1}}$ is the equivalence class $(r_{1}, s_{1})$. Of course one has to prove that these operations are well defined, i.e. they don't depend on the equivalence classes' representatives